# Correct way to re-run the failed tests with Selenium-Cucumber in kotlin jvm

Tags: java, selenium, kotlin, junit, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to re-run the failed functional tests for our application as I have seen these tests to be flaky.

Our setup is as follows

1. Platform / Stack - Kotlin 1.8.0 (JVM)
2. Webdriver - Selenium java:4.7.2
3. TestRunner - Cucumber Java8 (4.3.0) with Cucumber jUnit (4.3.0)

I have a `TestSuite.kt` which looks like below

```
import com.et.functionaltests.steps.WebDriverFactory
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber
import org.junit.AfterClass
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(Cucumber::class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = ["html:report", "pretty", "rerun:target/rerun.txt"])
object TestSuite {
    @JvmStatic
    @AfterClass
    fun teardown() {
        WebDriverFactory.close()
    }
}
```

As you can see I tried adding the `"rerun:target/rerun.txt"` in the plugins list after reading multiple solutions on the stack overflow I have also added another dependency
`testImplementation("org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2")` following this [article](https://medium.com/@belek.bagishbekov/how-to-rerun-failed-test-cases-in-cucumber-b7fe9b1dcf9c)

I have also created a another class called `FailedRunner.kt` whose content is as below

```
import com.et.functionaltests.steps.WebDriverFactory
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber
import org.junit.AfterClass
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(Cucumber::class)
@CucumberOptions(features = ["@target/rerun.txt"])
object FailedRunner {
    @JvmStatic
    @AfterClass
    fun teardown() {
        WebDriverFactory.close()
    }
}
```

So after all this when I run the test using the gradle command `ENV=dev gradle clean test` it runs FailedRunner first and then the TestSuit. I Would love to hear and learn more about fixing this and also proper way of doing this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using Gradle, why do you have a dependency on a Maven Plugin? That's a different build system.

Comment: Yes that was a mistake, I have removed it :)

Comment: Did you try multiple test tasks, with one dependent on the other? Or fixing the test order in a single task?